# Converting React class component to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have one class component, I would like to convert it to functional component. But I don't know exactly how to get it working:

My class component:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import Data from '../data';
import nextTime from '../next-time;

class TimesSingleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Times: this.getTimes(),
      tomorrowsTimes: this.getTomorrowsTimes(),
    };
  }

  getTimes() {
    var _data = new Data();
    return _data.getTimes();
  }

  getTomorrowsTimes() {
    var date = moment()
      .add(1, 'days')
      .format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    var _data = new Data();
    return _data.getTimes(date);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would set up what you have shown as a functional component. I used `useMemo` since you didn't show any modifications to the state values, but you can easily switch to useState instead.

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Data from '../data';
import nextTime from '../next-time;


const TimesSingleView = ()=>{
  const times = useMemo(()=>getTimes());
  const tomorrowsTimes = useMemo(()=>getTomorrowsTimes());
  // If you need to make changes to the times/ tomorrowsTimes, use them as state instead
  // const [times,setTimes] = useState(()=>getTimes());

}

function getTimes(){
  const data = new Data();
  return data.getTimes();
}

function getTomorrowsTimes() {
  const date = moment()
    .add(1, 'days')
    .format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  const _data = new Data();
  return _data.getTimes(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at hooks https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks